# How to hold UI from updating in WPF

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, user-interface

How can I suspend all UI elements from updating, then change anything I want and open multiple windows and ..., then resume UI and let it update at once?

I need it because I want to open multiple tabs with contents at once, but don't like to show user the flickers and multiple refreshes.

Comment: How long does the flickering go on for?

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to supsend the UI. If you use data binding you can update on the data context what you want. Until you don't call the PropertyChanged event on the DataContext, nothing will be updated.

Comment: But I am openning Docked windows and loading content and blah blah, it's not limited to bindings.

Comment: @AVEbrahimi Maybe you should consider binding.  +1

Answer (score 0):

Use Win32 API functions LockwindowUpdate and UnLockWindowUpdate

refer below article for more details.
http://weblogs.asp.net/jdanforth/archive/2004/03/12/88458.aspx